# UIScrollView Failing to Scroll

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` with a fair bit of content in it. The structure is shown below:

[image]

However, my scrollview isn't allowing a scroll to occur. I have made sure AutoLayout is off and the scrollview is larger than the screen size. The ScrollView isn't altered in the .h or .m files in any way. Any ideas why it may not be scrolling? The settings are default for the scrollview (essentially dragged and dropped in IB). ScrollView sizes as below

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `UIScrollView` should be ***equal to or smaller*** than your screen. The *content* of your scroll view should be larger than your scroll view's frame. (It is the content of the scroll view that scrolls within the bounds of the scroll view's frame.)

Then, in code, do something like this:

```
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(contentWidth, contentHeight)];
[scrollView setScrollEnabled:TRUE];
```

Comment: I tried with the size smaller than the screen, but this little bit of code did the trick! Not sure why it wouldn't work without the code :/ Also, I couldn't seem to use contentWidth and contentHeight, I had to use actual values (unless I'm being stupid!). Any ideas?

Comment: By `contentWidth` and `contentHeight` I was implying that you should replace them with the appropriate values, so you're doing it right. Please accept my answer if it helped!

Comment: Yeah I was thinking that's what you meant. Should I go for the default screen size? At the moment I've got 320 and 536. And I was just about to :)

Comment: Well, it depends on what you have in your scroll view. The `contentSize` of your scroll view should be equal to the size it would be if you could view everything in it without scrolling (basically the width of everything in it and the height of everything in it). Not sure if that was a good explanation haha. And thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The scrollView should (typically) NOT be larger than your screen size.

It's NOT the scrollView that scrolls, it's the content IN the scrollView that scrolls.

So set the contentSize of your scrollView to the appropriate size of your content and keep the scrollView itself within the bounds of the screen.